# Details of Google Cloud SQL billing and free quota

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm looking in to Google Apps Engine to host a php application and it all looks good so far.

The one area where I'm a bit unclear is Google Cloud SQL.  I have read through all the pricing info here, https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/pricing, but I don't see anything about a free usage quota.  I would be surprised if it doesn't exist however (since you can do everything else for free - at least for alpha and beta applications).

Am I missing something?  Is there a free tier or not?  Is it perhaps included in the Google Apps Engine free quota?  (I don't see it mentioned in https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/pricing)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no free quota for Google Cloud SQL. I'm pretty sure you have to pay from the start. Is there anyway you could possibly fit the Datastore to your requirements?

Answer (score 2):

It was offered as a 6-month trial. Right now there is no on-going trail.

Answer (score 1):

There is no free quota as of now. The site says, that you can try out the service for just $0.025/h, and you only pay this while the instance is being used